# this is error ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified?

Tags: c#, oracle, excel-addins

I've this code :

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("data source=localhost;user id=fastecit;password=fastecit"); 
con.Open(); string sql="Select userId from tblusers";    
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, con);
OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{ messageBox.Show(dr[0].Tostring()); }
```

Same code in both projects,

in project1 "WinForm" Is Working correctly

in project2 "Excel 2007 addins" Following error appears:

> ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

I'm using C#.net 2010 ,office 2007 , windows8, oracle 10g.

When preparing a manual connection to the database, as shown in the picture

Visual Studio, open View menu + Server Explorer.

Right mouse click on Data Connection + Add Connection + Select Oracle Database
server Name : localhost or name of my machine, set username & password and click on Test Connection, test is  no succeeds.[image]

Comment: don't you have to specify the database name somewhere ?

Comment: Yes, I can not specify the database somewhere

Comment: The same code works correctly in Project1 "winForms" and on the same machine, but it does not work in another project "Excel 2007 addins"

Comment: Is either project1 or project2 64-bit? Do you have more than one Oracle Home in your PATH environment variable?

Comment: project1 "winForms" Platform =x86 , output type =WindoseApplaciton.Project2 Platform =active any cpu,output type "Class Library"

Comment: Related, where the setup of environmental variables can also cause this issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957955/ora-12154-could-not-resolve-the-connect-identifier-specified/37971815#37971815

Comment: This is why you don't rely on Visual Studio tools to add your connection string. Learn how to create and enter in the string manually, so you understand the parameters, where they go, how they are used, and where they come from. The dialog is missing an entry for `SERVICE_NAME` or `SID`, and so cannot be used to accurately create a correct connection string.  https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle is a good reference.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified?**

In case the TNS is not defined you can also try this one:

If you are using `C#.net 2010` or other version of VS and oracle 10g express edition or lower version, and you make a connection string like this:

```
static string constr = @"Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=yourhostname )(PORT=1521)))
    (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=XE)));
    User Id=system ;Password=yourpasswrd";
```

After that you get error message `ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified` then first you have to do restart your system and run your project.

And if Your windows is 64 bit then you need to install oracle 11g 32 bit and if you installed 11g 64 bit then you need to Install Oracle 11g Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio version 11.2.0.1.2 or later from OTN and check it in Oracle Universal Installer
Please be sure that the following are checked:

```
Oracle Data Provider for .NET 2.0

Oracle Providers for ASP.NET

Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio

Oracle Instant Client
```

And then restart your Visual Studio and then run your project ....
NOTE:- SYSTEM RESTART IS necessary TO SOLVE THIS TYPES OF ERROR.......

Comment: thank u.. directly using the description in connection string solves this issue...

Comment: You have to reboot what ? the client or the server ? Usually you can solve "reboot" issues by only restarting some specific services..

Comment: It works and you saved my day, thank you! If not, just try to change HOST dns name to IP address.

Comment: Restarting the client machine made it work for me. Before that, I had trouble even testing the connection from the ODBC tool. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The database must have a name (example DB1), try this one:

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("data source=DB1;user id=fastecit;password=fastecit");
```

In case the TNS is not defined you can also try this one:

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=DB1)));
User Id=fastecit;Password=fastecit");
```

Comment: i've not DB1 , i used case 2 error "ORA-06413: Connection not open"

Comment: C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora

,XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = pcmax)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

Comment: I hope that you will help me @Wernfried

Comment: Then it is this: `OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("data source=XE;user id=fastecit;password=fastecit");`

Comment: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor is the error I get now.

Comment: Then the DB has a problem. Try to restart or ask your DBA

Comment: The `SERVICE_NAME` might not be `XE` or `DB1` - as stated, the DBA would be able to let you know what this is.  `XE` is just the default for Oracle Express.  It could've also been set up with a `SID`, instead, in which case you'd have to alter the connection string to put that in, instead of `SERVICE_NAME`.

Answer (score 2):

run the below command in command prompt

tnsping Datasource

This should give a response like below

C:>tnsping *******

TNS Ping Utility for *** Windows: Version *** - Production on *****

Copyright (c) 1997, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
c:\oracle*****

Used **** to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact **(description=(address_list=(address=(protocol=tcp)(host=******)(port=****)))(connect_data=(server=****)(service_name=****)(failover_mode=(type=****)(method=****)(retries=****)(delay=****))))**
OK (**** msec)

Add the text 'Datasource=' in beginning and credentials at the end.
the final string should be

**Data Source=(description=(address_list=(address=(protocol=tcp)(host=******)(port=****)))(connect_data=(server=****)(service_name=****)(failover_mode=(type=****)(method=****)(retries=****)(delay=****))));User Id=****;Password=****;**

Use this as the connection string to connect to oracle db.