# C# connect with Oracle DB error ORA-12154

Tags: c#, oracle11g, ora-12154

I have VS2013 installed and am trying to build a C# application with an active connection to Oracle database. I have Oracle 11g 64 bit on my Windows 8.1
I have also installed Oracle Development Tools for VS2013.But when I try to make a new connection from Server Explorer by choosing Oracle Database and server name as XE I get the following error

```
ORA-12154 TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

I followed the steps on this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361325/this-is-error-ora-12154-tnscould-not-resolve-the-connect-identifier-specified)

But I still get the same error.Any help?