# Opening Oracle OleDb connection succeeds, while managed driver connection fails

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oracle-manageddataaccess

From C# I'm connecting to Oracle using OleDb doing the following:

```
String connectionString = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=x;Password=y;Data Source=z";

var connection = new System.Data.OleDbConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
```

That works fine.

From the same process, I'm trying to connect using the managed driver doing the following:

```
String connectionString = "USER ID=x;PASSWORD=y;DATA SOURCE=z";

var connection = new Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
```

That fails with the following error:

```
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified ---> OracleInternal.Network.NetworkException (0x00002F7A): ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
   at OracleInternal.Network.AddressResolution..ctor(String TNSAlias, String instanceName)
   at OracleInternal.Network.OracleCommunication.DoConnect(String tnsDescriptor)
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.Connect(ConnectionString cs, Boolean bOpenEndUserSession, String instanceName)

Server stack trace: 
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.Get(ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, Boolean bGetForApp, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Get(ConnectionString csWithNewPassword, Boolean bGetForApp, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get(ConnectionString cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword, SecureString securedProxyPassword)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
```

I've received errors like this in the past when there was a problem with tnsnames, but I've never had a situation where OleDb works when the managed driver doesn't.

I've double checked and the user, password, and datasource are identical in the two connection strings.

Comment: What is in your TNSNames?

Comment: Could you try .. without TNS names?   https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-data-provider-for-net-odp-net/using-odpnet-without-tnsnamesora/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ODP.NET Managed driver uses a different way of looking for `tnsnames.ora`, resp. `sqlnet.ora` than OraOLEDB does.

For example, OraOLEDB reads the Registry for `TNS_ADMIN` value, whereas ODP.NET Managed driver does not. See [Determining locatation of relevant tnsnames.ora file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280883/determining-locatation-of-relevant-tnsnames-ora-file/28283924#28283924) for more details.

One solution is to set an Environment variable `TNS_ADMIN` with folder name where `tnsnames.ora` and `sqlnet.ora` files are located. As far as I know the Environment variables takes precedence over (almost) all other setting in both, ODP.NET Managed driver and OraOLEDB.

Comment: This turned out to be the case. ODP couldn't locate tnsnames even though OleDb could.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your TNSNames isnt setup correctly. You could also do a connection string like this to get around using tnsnames

```
static string constr = @"Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=
         (ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=yourhostname )(PORT=1521)))
         (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=XE)));
        User Id=system ;Password=yourpasswrd";
```

[this is error ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361325/this-is-error-ora-12154-tnscould-not-resolve-the-connect-identifier-specified)

Comment: Thanks. This workaround got me connected (as did Oracle's Easy Connect format -  host:[port]/[service_name]). But actual problem turned out to be that ODP driver couldn't locate tnsnames even when OleDb could.