# Sql query is working fine in sqlplus command prompt but when i running through sqldeveloper then getting the following error-

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus, dblink

Sql query is working fine in sqlplus command prompt but when i running through sqldeveloper then getting the following error-

Query :-  SELECT COUNT(1) FROM omnix.ngi_antenna_v@nc_mbn_omnix_prod;

Error :-

ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

12154. 00000 -  "TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified"

*Cause:    A connection to a database or other service was requested using

```
       a connect identifier, and the connect identifier specified could not

       be resolved into a connect descriptor using one of the naming methods

       configured. For example, if the type of connect identifier used was a

       net service name then the net service name could not be found in a

       naming method repository, or the repository could not be

       located or reached.
```

*Action:

```
       - If you are using local naming (TNSNAMES.ORA file):

       - Make sure that "TNSNAMES" is listed as one of the values of the

       NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH parameter in the Oracle Net profile

       (SQLNET.ORA)

       - Verify that a TNSNAMES.ORA file exists and is in the proper

       directory and is accessible.

       - Check that the net service name used as the connect identifier

       exists in the TNSNAMES.ORA file.

       - Make sure there are no syntax errors anywhere in the TNSNAMES.ORA

       file.  Look for unmatched parentheses or stray characters. Errors

       in a TNSNAMES.ORA file may make it unusable.

       - If you are using directory naming:

       - Verify that "LDAP" is listed as one of the values of the

       NAMES.DIRETORY_PATH parameter in the Oracle Net profile

       (SQLNET.ORA).

       - Verify that the LDAP directory server is up and that it is

       accessible.

       - Verify that the net service name or database name used as the

       connect identifier is configured in the directory.

       - Verify that the default context being used is correct by

       specifying a fully qualified net service name or a full LDAP DN

       as the connect identifier

       - If you are using easy connect naming:

       - Verify that "EZCONNECT" is listed as one of the values of the

       NAMES.DIRETORY_PATH parameter in the Oracle Net profile

       (SQLNET.ORA).

       - Make sure the host, port and service name specified

       are correct.

       - Try enclosing the connect identifier in quote marks.
```

Error at Line: 1 Column: 42

Please let me know if anyone know the solution for this. it would be great help.

Comment: Please reply if anyone aware this issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this is error ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361325/this-is-error-ora-12154-tnscould-not-resolve-the-connect-identifier-specified)