# .Net core 2.0 with oracle db connection

Tags: asp.net-core

with current .Ora file we are able to connect in .net 2.0 and 3.5 and unable to connect with .net core 2.0 , whether we need to modify the .ora file compared to old one. please tell the steps

OracleInternal.Network.NetworkException (0x00002F7A): *ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified*
   at OracleInternal.Network.AddressResolution..ctor(String TNSAlias, String instanceName)
   at OracleInternal.Network.OracleCommunication.DoConnect(String tnsDescriptor)
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.Connect(ConnectionString cs, Boolean bOpenEndUserSession, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String instanceName)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.Get(ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Get(ConnectionString csWithNewPassword, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get(ConnectionString cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword, SecureString securedProxyPassword, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
   at TodoApi.Startup.b__5_0(HttpContext context) in D:\Samples\TodoApi\TodoApi\Startup.cs:line 68}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-12154 could not resolve the connect identifier specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957955/ora-12154-could-not-resolve-the-connect-identifier-specified)

Answer (score 0):

Put correct configuration in tns .ora file inside app client folder or check your connection string in json file.