# I inatalled Oracle db 19c and login as user sys as sysdba the error,"ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified" accured

Tags: database, oracle, sqlplus, rdbms, sysdba

Error "ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified" accuring while logging in as "sys as sysdba" with password . But then I read an article saying that,"admin privilages let's a sysdba login without a password." and I tried that and immediately got connected to sql server . Can anyone tell me why this happened ? and why login with password isn't working with this .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ORA-12154 could not resolve the connect identifier specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957955/ora-12154-could-not-resolve-the-connect-identifier-specified)

Comment: @pmda has given an explanation of two distinct issues.  Please allow me to point out that you are asking us to debug your connection without actually seeing the specific connection string/command you used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify `sqlplus sys as sysdba` with the correct ORACLE_SID environment variable set from the DB server, Oracle uses OS-authentication to authenticate sys and BEQ protocol (no network) to connect. That's why it would work without a password.

Connecting to `sqlplus sys/password@tnsname as sysdba` connects across a network (your error indicates that your tnsname wasn't resolved) and requires that a separate password file be configured for authentication. See here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/dba.htm#ADMIN11056