# Oracle database SQLPLUS: How to enter password has character @?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Oracle database 21c express edition on Windows 11.

[image]

My error

```
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

[image]

My password is `xxxxxa@` . I see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67141887/3728901 How to enter password?

Update: Thank to Connor's answer. I catch

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1889]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Administrator>sqlplus /nolog

SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Thu Aug 25 10:21:18 2022
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL> connect sys/"123456a@"@xe
ERROR:
ORA-28009: connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER


SQL>
```

[image]

Comment: type `sqlplus /nolog` then `connect sys/"123456a@"@xe as sysdba`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double quotes are your friend here

```
SQL> create user XXX identified by 123@456;
create user XXX identified by 123@456
                                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option


SQL> create user XXX identified by "123@456";

User created.

SQL> grant create session to xxx;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect xxx/123@456@db19_pdb1
ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified


Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
SQL> connect xxx/"123@456"@db19_pdb1 as sysdba
Connected.
```

Comment: Thank you. I catch `ERROR: ORA-28009: connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER`

Comment: That is indeed correct. You almost never need to connect as SYS unless you are doing some serious database admin stuff.  If you *do* need to do it, then its "connect abc/edf@db as sysdba".  But to create users etc etc, you can connect as SYSTEM and that should be fine.  Don't put your OWN objects in SYS or SYSTEM - create your own user for that. eg. https://www.youtube.com/shorts/lb6E_Z5Op6w

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlplus /nolog
connect sys/"123456a@"@xe as sysdba

SQL> alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;  
SQL> create user donhuvy identified by "123456a@";
SQL> grant create session to donhuvy;
SQL> connect donhuvy/"123456a@"@xe
```